# ¿Cómo solucionar este error y qué significa en vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <categoria> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

(found in <Root>)
warn @ app.js:22035
createElm @ app.js:26928
updateChildren @ app.js:27204
patchVnode @ app.js:27295
updateChildren @ app.js:27181
patchVnode @ app.js:27295
patch @ app.js:27455
Vue._update @ app.js:24102
updateComponent @ app.js:24220
get @ app.js:24570
run @ app.js:24647
flushSchedulerQueue @ app.js:24409
(anonymous) @ app.js:23268
flushCallbacks @ app.js:23189
```

Answer (score 1):

Vue JS es una librería front-end de javascript. Me imagino que no estás familiarizado con este framework y me imagino estás usando el script que viene por defecto en la plantilla de fábrica de laravel. Si quieres seguir usando el framework "Vue JS" te sugiero le eches un ojo a la [documentación](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/). De lo contrario, crea tu propia plantilla y usa algún lenguaje con algún framework front-end (si lo necesitas) al que estés familiarizado.

Regresando al error se debe a que estás usando un nombre diferente para los componentes:

```
components: {
      'componente' : Componente,
      'otrocomponente': OtroComponente
    }
```

Debes de usar también el mismo nombre mientras exportas:

```
name: 'OtroComponente'
```